# Should I charge a 3.7 V 500 mAh battery with a 5.2 V mobile charger?

Tags: lithium, lithium-polymer

I don't have the Li-Po charger but the mobile charger I have outputs 1 A and 5.2 V. So should I charge it?

I completely drained my battery by the way.

Comment: What does the battery manufacturer recommend for their product?

Comment: You have to have a lipo charger, or a power supply that can do constant voltage\constant current

Comment: Buy a USB Lipo battery charger module, which is really cheap and connect your battery and charger to the module to charge it.

Comment: Can we just respond to all of these questions with a "please film the massive fire" comment?  There's about 2 a day.

Comment: *I completely drained my battery by the way* That will also help making your battery wear out more quickly. **Never** completely discharge Lithium based batteries. Always stop discharging at around 3 to 3.5 V.

Answer (score 4):

Your "mobile charger" is actually just a 5.2V Constant Voltage power supply, which is unsuitable for directly charging batteries, so **no**.

Doing so might result in fires/explosions.

The battery "charger" of mobile devices is actually inside the cellphone/tablet, not on the USB power supply.